I have a question about Harthshorne Algebraic Geometry Thorem3.2
Section1, Theorem 3.2. Let $Y \subseteq A^n$ be an affine variety with affine coordinate ring $A(Y)$ Then
(a) $\mathcal{O}(Y) \cong A(Y)$;
(b) for each point $P \in Y$, let $\mathfrak{m}_p \subseteq A(Y)$ be the ideal of functions vanishing at $P$. Then $P \mapsto \mathfrak{m}_p$ gives a 1-1 correspondence between the points of $Y$ and the maximal ideals of $A(Y)$;
(c)for each $P,\mathcal{O}_p \cong A(Y)_{\mathcal{m}_P}$, and dim$\mathcal{O}_p$ = dim$Y$;...
I have a question what is definition of $A(Y)_{\mathcal{m}_P}$?

The notation $A(Y)_{\mathfrak{m}_p}$ stands for the localization of the coordinate ring $A(Y)$ at the ideal ${\mathfrak{m}_p}$, i.e. at the multiplicative subset given by all those elements of $A(Y)$ which do not lie in the ideal ${\mathfrak{m}_p}$.
To give an example of such a localization, consider the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ and the prime ideal $(2) = 2\mathbb{Z}$ generated by the number $2$. Then the localization $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ is created by adding multiplicative inverses of all the integers in $\mathbb{Z} \setminus 2 \mathbb{Z}$, i.e of all the odd integers, to the integers $\mathbb{Z}$. Concretely this is the subring of the rational numbers given by those fractions $\frac{a}{b}$ with $b$ odd.

It's called localization and it is a similar construction to the fraction field but allowing only certain elements to appear as a denominator. Somewhat annoyingly, there are two kinds of localization used in algebraic geometry: making a prime number a denominator and making everything not divisible a prime number a denominator. (Or sets of prime numbers.)

If $A$ is a ring and $f \in A$ then
$$
A_f = \left\{ \frac{a}{f^n} : a \in A, n \ge 0 \right\}
$$
If $A$ is a ring and $P$ is a prime ideal, then
$$
A_P = \left\{ \frac ab : a \in A, b \notin P \right\}
$$

Type 1 is roughly saying: we're imposing $f \neq 0$ because it can now appear in the denominator.
Type 2 is saying: I want to look at prime ideals which are contained in $P$ and so I'm going to make everything else a unit.
You might remember that ideals of $A / P$ correspond to ideals of $A$ which contain $P$. It is a similar theorem that (prime) ideals of $A_P$ are prime ideals of $A$ which are contained in $P$. They have to be prime because some of the nonprime ideals might end up containing units.
Geometrically, primes correspond to closed subvarieties. So like in the plane we have a prime ideal corresponding to the point $(0, 0)$, I.e. $(x, y)$. If we localize at this (add denominators for everything not in this ideal) then we are looking at prime ideals (subvarieties) which contain the point $(0, 0)$—remember the inclusion is reversed. For example, $y = x^2$ goes through the point $(0, 0)$ so $(y - x^2)$ will be an ideal in the localization.
